# Is it possible to log MySQL Errors to text file, when MySQL queries are executed using Stored Procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, text-files

I want to log MySql Errors to a text file, when MySql queries are executed using Stored Procedure.
I want any sample syntax so that I can put them into my stored procedure and log errors into a text file when an error occurred.

Thank you in Advance

Comment: *I want to log MySql Errors to a text file* `@@datadir/data/*.err`. *when MySql queries are executed using Stored Procedure* What kind of errors do you mean?

Comment: Error in the sense, when we execute any MySql query if the syntax of the query is wrong, it should be logged into the text file

Comment: In common when syntax error occures the SP execution is aborted. Do you want to save the statement which causes the error and abort SP? if so then declare according handler, retrieve the statement from the processlist, save it to a separate (appending to existing file or rewriting it is impossible) file (use SELECT .. INTO OUTFILE) then resignal the error.

Comment: From the other side "current statement" may be retrieved only in the most first BEFORE trigger (and only in `SET @var = (SELECT INFO ...)`). In all other cases you'll obtain retrieving query.

Comment: Thank you for the response is there are sample codes I can try or refer because I'm New to SP

Comment: I recommend you to investigate Reference Manual for [MySQL server logs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-logs.html) (general log firstly). Enable it temporarily, execute your SP, disable log, investigate its content. Maybe this will be enough for your purposes...

Comment: Thank you Akina for the response, I'll try your suggestion